# Set a delay in a JS file to call upon a JS file

Tags: javascript, delay

I am trying to have one Javascript file to be loaded by another, but I want the second file to be loaded after a delay.  What do I need to add to this to get a delay?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "https://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/yhst-136932942155053/BongoCheckout.Yahoo.2.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script);
});
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` to delay for X milliseconds before loading the Javascript file.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "https://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/yhst-136932942155053/BongoCheckout.Yahoo.2.js";
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    },2000);  // 2000 is the delay in milliseconds
});
```

`setTimeout` will run the function you give it after a number of milliseconds.

See this [MDN Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) for more official stuff about `setTimeout`.

Also, `getElementsByTagName` is a lousy way to get the body.  Use `document.body` instead.

Here's a simple demo on `setTimeout`: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/Xazf7/1/).

Comment: Thank you! I would up your answer, if I had 15 points worth of rep. Thanks!

Comment: Here's a demo of `setTimeout` : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/Xazf7/1/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.setTimeout(func, millisecs)`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "https://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/yhst-136932942155053/BongoCheckout.Yahoo.2.js";
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script);
    }, 1000); // 1 sec
});
```

Comment: Thank you, will accept the answer in 8 minutes. Thanks again.